# ERROR DART: The name 'x' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument

Tags: flutter, dart

Error in the Input part in one class and in Output in another class

1. This would be the main class referenced

```
abstract class HttpFunction<Input, Output>
{
  Output apply(Input paramInput);
}
```

2. This would be the class in which the previous one is called

```
class ComposerFunction with HttpFunction<Input, Request>
{
    RequestComposer<Input> inputConverter;

    ComposerFunction(RequestComposer inputConverter);

    ComposerFunction_(RequestComposer<Input> inputConverter)
    {
        this.inputConverter = inputConverter;
    }

    Request apply(Input input)
    {
        return this.inputConverter.compose(input);
    }
}

class InterpreterFunction with HttpFunction<Response, Output> 
{
    ResponseInterpreter<Output> responseInterpreter;

    InterpreterFunction(ResponseInterpreter outputConverter);

    InterpreterFunction_(ResponseInterpreter<Output> responseInterpreter)
    {
        this.responseInterpreter = responseInterpreter;
    }

    Output apply(Response response)
    {
        return this.responseInterpreter.interpret(response);
    }
}
```

3. These are the Errors

```
The name 'Input' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'Input'.dart(non_type_as_type_argument)
```

And

```
The name 'Output' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'Output'.dart(non_type_as_type_argument)
```

**UPDATE**

```
class ComposerFunction<Input> implements HttpFunction<Input, Request>
{
    ...
}

class InterpreterFunction<Output> implements HttpFunction<Response, Output>
{
   ...
}
```

Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```dart
class ComposerFunction with HttpFunction<Input, Request>
{
   ...
}
```

Assuming that you want `ComposerFunction` to be a generic class that can be parameterized on caller-specified `Input` and `Request` types, you have not declared `ComposerFunction` to be a generic class.  Although `HttpFunction` *is* a generic class, `ComposerFunction` as written is a *non*-generic class that uses `HttpFunction` specialized with types literally named `Input` and `Request`.  If you don't have classes named `Input` and `Request`, this therefore fails with:

> The name 'Input' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.

to make `ComposerFunction` a generic class, you need to add type parameters to *it*:

```dart
class ComposerFunction<Input, Request> with HttpFunction<Input, Request>
{
   ...
}
```

Same thing applies to `InterpreterFunction`.

Additionally, `with` is normally intended for use with [`mixin`s](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#adding-features-to-a-class-mixins). It's also allowed with `abstract class` for backward compatibility with Dart 2.0 and earlier, but since `HttpFunction` does not provide any code that can be reused, this doesn't seem useful. If you want `ComposerFunction` (and `InterpreterFunction`) to conform to an interface, then you usually would use `implements` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has solved the problem for me, but another one has come up. In the first class, in 'Request apply ()' it gives me the following error
`A value of type 'Request can't be returned from method 'apply' because it has a return type of 'Request'.dart(return_of_invalid_type)`
and in the second class, in 'Output apply ()'
`The argument type 'Response' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Response'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable) `

Comment: @jamesdlin, I have the same error but am not building off an abstract class so I'm a little confused on how to fix it. My declaration is
class PushNotificationService {...}

and usage is
locator<PushNotificationService>().unsubscribeFromTopic(appCode);

How do I make that generic?

Comment: @jamesdin, please disregard my comment. I missed an import in the usage... 

Answer (score 0):

If generically passing types is what you're after, could you try changing your abstract class as below

```
abstract class HttpFunction<T, U>
{
  U apply<T, U>(T paramInput);
}
```

And the classes as follows:

```
class ComposerFunction with HttpFunction<Input, Request>
{
    RequestComposer<Input> inputConverter;

    ComposerFunction(RequestComposer inputConverter);

    ComposerFunction_(RequestComposer<Input> inputConverter)
    {
        this.inputConverter = inputConverter;
    }

    Request apply<Input, Request>(Input input)
    {
        return this.inputConverter.compose(input);
    }
}
class InterpreterFunction with HttpFunction<Response, Output>
{
    ResponseInterpreter<Output> responseInterpreter;

    InterpreterFunction(ResponseInterpreter outputConverter);

    InterpreterFunction_(ResponseInterpreter<Output> responseInterpreter)
    {
        this.responseInterpreter = responseInterpreter;
    }

    Output apply<Response, Output>(Response response)
    {
        return this.responseInterpreter.interpret(response);
    }
}
```

This is assuming you have classes created/referenced of the expected types

Comment: Have you created/imported Input and Output classes in your file?

Comment: Yes i imported them

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any errors on dartpad. i have declared rest of classes. Could you post rest of the classes if that's feasible?